# How to solve the issue: "Refused to set unsafe header "content-length" with Flutter and Node.js

Tags: node.js, flutter, express

I'm working in a custom auth API for my own projects with Node.js and Express. This is the server configuration that I've tried so far:

```
const express = require('express');
export const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const authRoutes = require('./routes/authRoutes');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();

//middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use((req: any, res: any, next: any) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Content-Type, Content-Length');
  next();
});

//database connection
const dbURI = process.env.DB_URI;

mongoose.connect(dbURI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
  .then((result: any) =>{
    app.listen( process.env.PORT || 3000, () => console.log('Server is running and connected to MongoDB') );
  })
  .catch((err: any) => console.error(err));

//routes
app.get('/', (req: any, res: any) => res.send('Welcome to my own custom auth system!'));
app.get('/about', (req: any, res: any ) => res.send('This is my custom auth system made with Node.js, Express.js, MongoDB, Mongoose, and Typescript and I use it for my own projects!. This auth system uses JWT for authentication and cookies for authorization as well as bcrypt for hashing passwords and mongo db for storing user data.'));

app.use(authRoutes);
```

I know this is a CORS related issue, but I thought the configuration shown above would help to eliminate this issue because with this line `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')`, I'm saying that it should accept request from any client and this line `res.header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Content-Type, Content-Length');` it's supposed to help with the issue that I'm having, but it's not working.

I'm doing the post request to create a new user in my MongoDB from a Flutter web app, which is an admin dashboard. So the request in that Flutter app looks like this:

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import '../constants/constants.dart';

final connect = GetConnect();

Future<String> userSignup(String username, String email, String password) async {
  try{
    var result = await connect.post(
      '${Constants.localHost}/signup',
      { 'username': username, 'email': email, 'password': password},
    );
    return result.body['msg'];
  }catch(e){
    return e.toString();
  }
}
```

The request works perfectly fine (I can create the user and save all the data in mongo), but in my server, besides creating the user, I want to set up a cookie with user info. This is the code for that part:

```
import { User } from '../models/user';
import { hashPassword, handleErrors, createToken } from '../utils/auth';

export const signup = async (req: any, res: any) => {
  const { username, email, password } = req.body;

  const hashedPassword = await hashPassword(password);

  const maxAge = 3 * 24 * 60 * 60;
  
  try{
    const createdUser = await User.create({ username: username, email: email, password: hashedPassword });
    const token = createToken(createdUser._id, maxAge);
    res.cookie('jwt', token, { httpOnly: true, maxAge: maxAge * 1000 });
    res.status(201).json({ msg: 'User created successfully!' });
  }catch(e){
    const errors = handleErrors(e);
    res.status(400).json({ errors });
  }

}
```

With all of this, I'm still getting the error 'Refused to set unsafe header "content-length"'.

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Just so you know guys, I already solved the requirement of setting the cookie in the browser, but I did it in the front end (flutter app). I'm leaving this question still open, because I'm really intrigued by this and I really want to know if somebody can give an answer to achieve this from the server. Thanks.

Comment: can you post the front end side code

Comment: I think I already did... or can you be more specific about which part?

Comment: The part that you configured cookie setting in the front end.

Comment: If you want to see what I did, you can check out my GitHub repo: https://github.com/thegera4/flutter_web_ecommerce (a star would be appreciated ;) )